# How do I get the sum of group by in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SSN,8,1), COUNT(*)
FROM HR
GROUP BY SUBSTR(SSN,8,1)
```

The result of

```
SUBSTR(SSN,8,1), COUNT(*)
1,32
2,30
```

How can I get the sum of group by, 32+30?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions if you want the total value on each row:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SSN, 8, 1), COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total_count
FROM HR
GROUP BY SUBSTR(SSN, 8, 1);
```

You can use `GROUPING SETS` if you want an additional row:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SSN, 8, 1), COUNT(*)
FROM HR
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (SUBSTR(SSN, 8, 1)), () );
```

Or for only the sum, you don't need `GROUP BY` at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM HR;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`ROLLUP()` or `CUBE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm) extensions such as

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SSN,8,1), COUNT(*)
  FROM HR
 GROUP BY ROLLUP( SUBSTR(SSN,8,1) )
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SSN,8,1), COUNT(*)
  FROM HR
 GROUP BY CUBE( SUBSTR(SSN,8,1) )
```